# How To Stop Caching Of Web Pages In IE

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching

I am using an app (developed in ASP.NET but has ASP pages as well)
Whenever I visit the app, the pages are cached. in other words they don't reflect the new items in the database. I don't have access to the source code of the web app. I assumed it may be an Internet Explorer setting. So I checked a few settings and finally found a way to reload the page from server everytime I visit the page but the setting worked during the session but once I close the browser the setting is reset. 
I wonder if there is something that I am missing here. I am not a savvy web developer,

One more thing. The ASP.NET pages fetch new data but ASP pages don't. I am  not sure if that is of any relevance

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have IIS expire the content immediately so that it isn't cached. In IIS 7 (there are different ways to do this in earlier versions):

1) Select the web application

2) Double-click `HTTP Response Headers`

3) In the right-hand menu, select `Set Common Headers...`

4) Check the `Expire Web content` checkbox and ensure the `Immediately` radio button is selected

5) Click `Ok`